# Date insert php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I guess I have it partially working, but it inserted a random year,day & month rather than the actual date now.

This is in my "Post Article" .php file.

```
<?php
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

What I have setup for my SQL table is this:

[image]

however it ends up showing this date:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: what in your `$timestamp` variable?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't pass a second parameters to `date()` it defaults to now.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

It would be even easier to do this in your SQL (and simultaneously make your PHP code simpler and easier to maintain). You can use several MySQL functions like `NOW()` and `CURDATE()`:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (date) VALUES(NOW())
INSERT INTO tablename (date) VALUES(CURDATE())
```

FYI, I can't say for sure since I can't see your code, but I suspect `$timestamp` doesn't exist in your code. That will cause you to get the value you see in your database.

Comment: @TrippedStackers, be also warn about correct mysql timezone setted for db functions